# Raising validation error in django form for the api

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django and python development and am naive in my understanding of how to handle exceptions.

I am registering a user through an api call by calling the method register, and would like to push the success status or the error messages while registration.

```
def register(self,request, **kwargs):

        try:    
            data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
            email = data['email']
            password = data['password']
            firstname = data['firstname']
            lastname = data['lastname']
            newdata = {'email' : email , 'password1': password , 'password2':password, 'firstname':'firstname' , 'lastname':lastname }

            registrationform = UserEmailRegistrationForm(newdata)
            print registrationform.errors.as_text
            print registrationform.cleaned_data
            cleaned_data = registrationform.cleaned_data
            if Site._meta.installed:
                site = Site.objects.get_current()
            else:
                site = RequestSite(request)

            new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(cleaned_data['username'],cleaned_data['email'],cleaned_data['password1'], site)
            signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                         user=new_user,
                                         request=request,**cleaned_data)
            registerUser = collections.OrderedDict()
            registerUser['return']='0'
            registerUser['code']='0'
            registerUser['message']='registered user'
            return HttpResponse(registerUser, content_type="application/json")
        except Exception, e:
            logging.exception(e)
            registerUser = collections.OrderedDict()
            registerUser['return']='0'
            registerUser['code']='0'
            registerUser['message']='registered user'
            return HttpResponse(registerUser, content_type="application/json")
```

When I execute this, for example with an already registered email, I get the following in registrationform.errors.as_text

```
bound method ErrorDict.as_text of {'email': [u'A user with that email already exists.']}>
```

What would be the right way to code exceptions so that I can pass the success message if the form was validated and user was registered, and the error message if there was a validation error?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look in the form's is_valid() method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid

For example

```
if registrationform.is_valid():
   //do your stuff
   ....
   register['error'] = False
else:
   //return the errors
   registerUser['message'] = _('Oops! Please fix the following errors')
   register['error'] = True
   register['errors'] = registrationform.errors
   ....
```